# Storing array into xml file

Tags: android

I want to store an array into a xml file.

The array will be called with the following function.

```
String getTextSpeech = TextSpeech[Index];
```

This is using the textToSpeechAPI.

How can I store the array TextSpeech[] in an xml file in the values folder and then call it within the class.

Thanks

Edit:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="myArray"> 
    <item>String1</item> 
    <item>String2</item> 
    <item>String3</item> 
</string-array> 
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In activity you can call it as

```
String[] resourceString =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
```

if your class is not of an activity type then use a contructor of class like

```
YourClass(Context activityContext)
{
     String[] resourceString =activityContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as I cannot use getResources in a class unless it is an activity. Also would this work in TextToSpeech by calling the strings in the xml, thanks

Comment: well if u want to use resources of android then class must of activity or of service subtype. but you can use it by passing context of activity to that class

Answer (score -1):

You cant store any thing in `values` at run times but what you want can be achieved through various data storage solutions provided by android http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

For your scenario I would suggest [SQLite Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already use a SQLite database for one of my applications and I need the other application to be developed in a different way so I can compare them  when I evaluate them. If I do store it in values like shown above. do you  know how I can call this using the function above. Thanks